# Проблема на с типами на пайтон

Tags: python, flask

```
def CreateTable():
    con = sqlite3.connect('Exhibition.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Crafts (ID int, META text, Design text, Photo text, Ratings text);''')
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

```
def GetPhotoFromDB(ID=0):
        con = sqlite3.connect('Exhibition.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
    
        for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Crafts'):  # ORDER BY META
            kek = row
            if row[0] == ID:
                break
        if kek[0] != ID:
            print('photo not found!!!', 'ID: ', ID, 'Index: ', kek[0])
            return 'photo no found'
    
        return kek[3]
        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

даже если kek[0] равно 2 и ID равно 2, то всё равно photo not found

пробовал создать переменную например

```
realID: int = 0
realID = kek[0]
```

но тоже не робит

Comment: Ты пробовал сделать for row in cur.execute(): print(row)? Чего выводит? И попробуй сделать после break'а (на уровне if'ов, выйдя из цикла) print(kek), чего выведет? Бтв мб тебе попробовать сделать чего то вроде "select... where ID = " + ID? Плюсом, где нибудь вкинь print(type(kek[0])) и print(type(ID)) и посмотри чего по типам напишет. У тебя мб возвращает kek[0] как строку, а не число.

Comment: Проверил на натуре, 1 как число int не равно 1 как строке str. Проверь типы или попробуй в сравнение вкинуть str(ID)

Comment: Подозреваю, что `fetchall()` забыли https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/sqlite-python-select/

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего `row[0]` возвращает строку. Не забывайте, что

```py
a = 1
b = '1'
print(a == b) # false
```

попробуйте сделать так:

```py
def GetPhotoFromDB(ID=0):
        con = sqlite3.connect('Exhibition.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
    
        for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Crafts'):  # ORDER BY META
            kek = row
            if row[0] == str(ID):
                break
        if kek[0] != str(ID):
            print('photo not found!!!', 'ID: ', ID, 'Index: ', kek[0])
            return 'photo no found'
    
        return kek[3]
        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

**P.S.**

Вы привели пример с данным кодом:

```py
realID: int = 0
realID = kek[0]
```

Сославшись на то, что он не помогает решить проблему. **Так и должно быть.**
Указание типа через `:type` указывает, какой тип у переменной `ожидается`. Но это не значит, что переменная не может быть другого типа.

То есть:

```py
real_id: int = 0
real_id = 123  # Сработает
real_id = 'Hello world!'  # Все-равно сработает.
```

Данное дополнение может быть полезно, например чтобы IDE типа PyCharm могли давать вам подсказки с возможными методами, например если вы уверены, что ваша функция вернет `list`, вы можете указать это способом, указанным выше, и ваше IDE будет предлагать вам возможные методы, считая, что ваша переменная имеет тип `list`. Но учтите, что если тип окажется НЕ `list`, это может вызвать ошибки.